# Inserting 'Attribute' type (from python 2.7 ldap3 package) with unicode characters into MySQL db

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, ldap, mariadb

I'm writing script which takes data form Active Directory and puts it into MySQL database.

```
tls = Tls(validate=ssl.CERT_NONE, version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
server = Server(serverName, use_ssl=True, tls=tls)
c = Connection(server, authentication=SASL, sasl_mechanism=KERBEROS)
c.bind()

c.search(dc, filter, attributes=['Name'])
```

I'm encountering some problems with unicode characters. For example, i have attribute that contains 'Ł' letter.

```
var = c.entries[0]['Name']
```

When i've been testing this code in interactive python mode, i realised few things:

```
type(var)

var

str(var)

type(var.value)

var.value

str(var.value)
```

Those lines print the following results:

```
<class 'ldap3.abstract.attribute.Attribute'>

name: Ł

'\xc5\x81'

<type 'unicode'>

u'\0141'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0141' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How to insert the 'Ł' char into the database instead of \u0141? I was trying encode/decode methods that i found in google solutions but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Where did the stroke-L come from?  A data file?  Typed into the source?  Other?  Do you have this at the start?  `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: The 'Ł' comes from Active Directory. I did't have that line, but it doesn't help, and as I mentioned below if i put special signs directly from textfield it works fine, but it gets broken while pulling data from Active Directory. The funny thing is that, if i run this function from file/interactive mode, it puts 'Ł' instead of byte form, but when i run it from flask, it gets broken.

Answer (score 0):

use decode() method before inserting it in database. it will store unicode instead of bytes.

Comment: Well, you are right, the following line:
```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TABLE(column) VALUES (%s)", [str(var).decode('utf8')])
```
works perfectly in the interactive mode, but when i run it from the flask script (textfield and "send" button are on website), it puts \u0141 in database instead. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: can you share the flask script with me?

Comment: Unfortunately i can't share the code, but i have a function that get's the data form Active Directory and puts it into the database, if i import and run this function from interactive mode it works perfectly, also when i run it from file it works. In flask i have literally
`if request.method == 'Post': Function()`
And it puts \u0141 in the db instead of 'Ł'. It is propably not related to file encoding because when I put data directly from textfields it also works fine. Only when i pull them from AD something gets broken.